# Why scanf statement and for loop not executed?

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

// To find the index of an array element
int main(){
int arr[20]; int n; int x;

```
printf("enter the no. of                  elements you want");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf (" enter the array elements of your wish");
for( int i =0;i<=n-1;i++){
   scanf("%d\n",&are[i]);
 }

printf("the array elements are");
for( int i =0;I<=n-1;i++){
printf("%d\n",are[i]);
}

printf("enter any value and you will see it's index");
scanf("%d",&x);

for( int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
if( x==arr[I]){ printf("%d",i);}
}

return 0;
}
```

I expected to get the following:
enter the number of elements you want (say5)
Enter the array elements of your wish (1 2 3 4 5....say)
The array elements are
1
2
3
4
5
Enter any number and you will see it's index ( say 5)
4

But,this is what I am getting:
enter the number of elements you want (say5)
Enter the array elements of your wish (1 2 3 4 5....say)
The array elements are
1
2
3
4
5
Enter any number and you will see it's index

- From here I can't scan and intake value and the following loop is not running. I don't understand why.

Comment: You have: `scanf("%d\n", &are[i]);` — that input won't terminate until after you type a number and then something else after the number other than white space (and white space includes newlines).  Drop the `\n` from the format string.  And you MUST check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure you got a valid value.  Every time you use it, check it.  And testing against EOF is almost always wrong; you want to ensure you got as many values as you expected.  You expect 1, so `if (scanf("%d", &are[I]) != 1) { …report error…; …break or return or exit…; }`.